# New process being created while checking with 'if' in bash

Tags: linux, shell-script, bash-scripting, ps

```
ps -ef | while read line; do
    for i in $line; do
        if [ $i = 'bash' ]; then
            echo $line;
        fi;
    done;
done;
unset i;
```

The command runs properly displaying the Bash processes but an additional Bash process is being created and displayed. I'm hoping it has something to do inside the `if` checking. I tried to run it with/without single/double quotes both for `$i` and `bash` inside the `if` condition. The process is still being created and shown. I could have used `grep` to get the output but wanted to try it this way.

Pls correct me.

Comment: [What are you _really_ trying to do?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Most likely you want to use [`pgrep`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pgrep) or a dedicated library instead. Manually parsing `ps` output is not what it's for, not least because of issues like this.

Answer (score 1):

The extra process is created by the pipe.

For more information read this [very good explanation of bash and the process tree](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/processtree).

Note that the output of `ps` is not designed to be parseable. When trying to parse `ps` you are most likely better of using `pgrep`.